# jQuery Draggable Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Im trying to get a `div` to be movable within the constrains of the browser window, by dragging the titlebar inside the `div`. My code is as follows:

```
<div id='container'>
    <h3 class='title' id='titlebar'>My Title</h3>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#titlebar").draggable({ containment: 'window', scroll: false, helper: $('#container') });
    });
</script>
```

Something is wrong with this (it wont do anything at all) but I cant see the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) syntax is a little different than you have, you need to set `.draggable()` on the element that you want draggable (`#container` in this case) then provide a selector to the [`handle` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-handle), like this:

```
$("#container").draggable({ 
  containment: 'window', 
  scroll: false, 
  handle: '#titlebar' 
});​​​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uBPs8/).

Comment: Thanks alot! I was trying to work this out from the jQuery docs and clearly got it quite wrong :)